# Rails - Twitter Bootstrap i18n - validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, twitter-bootstrap, internationalization

Is there some kind of register over what attributes there are in Twitter Bootstrap and how can I change the message that pops up?

Example: Validation on form,

Instead of "Please fill out this field." I want another translation. Is this somehow connected to the original active record error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message displayed `Please fill out this field` is an HTML5 validation. You can customize this message using the `setCustomValidity()` http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/#toc-constraint-validation

Also you can add some customized text to the message as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/nfgfP/8/

To use I18n in JavaScript you can checkout the i18n-js gem https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        e.target.checkValidity();
        e.target.setCustomValidity(__Msg(e.target.validationMessage));
    };
}

// translate messages
function __Msg(str){
    switch(str){
        case 'Please fill out this field.': return 'fill out plz.';break;
        case 'Please enter an email address.': return 'enter email plz.';break;

    }
    return str; // skip not translated messages
}
```